# Apache error log: Spawner output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger, spree

In my `error.log` from apache, I have a lot of the following output:

```
[ 2013-11-03 06:25:03.9381 12225/7f72feaa7740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:440 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_instances_per_app' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_pid' => '28490', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-11-03 06:25:04.0517 12228/7f64e3868740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:555 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.28490/generation-18/request
[ 2013-11-03 06:25:04.2718 12239/7f13012f7740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:271 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.28490/generation-18/logging
[ 2013-11-03 06:25:04.2721 12225/7f72feaa7740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:564 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[Sun Nov 03 06:25:04 2013] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Nov 03 06:25:04 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.5 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[ 2013-11-03 06:25:37.2513 12228/7f64e3771700 Pool2/Spawner.h:739 ]: [App 12429 stdout] 
[ 2013-11-03 06:25:54.3365 12228/7f64e3771700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:301 ]: Preloader for /var/www/production/current started on PID 12429, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.28490/generation-18/backends/preloader.12429
[ 2013-11-03 06:41:51.1811 12228/7f64e3771700 Pool2/Spawner.h:739 ]: [App 13186 stdout] 
[ 2013-11-03 06:42:08.1962 12228/7f64e3771700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:301 ]: Preloader for /var/www/production/current started on PID 13186, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.28490/generation-18/backends/preloader.13186
```

The last two lines are repeated over and over again, about every 30 minutes. I was wondering what that output means? I have 2 Rails apps running, using Spree Commerce as a shop system, they are monitored using New Relic, and running with Apache 2 and Passenger. So what does this Spawner stuff mean?

Furthermore, we have also some SQL output in the error logs, like

```
[ 2013-11-02 15:20:44.1366 23916/7fc8bde20700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1174 ]: [App 22784 stdout] D, [2013-11-02T15:20:44.136567 #22784] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `spree_taxons` WHERE `spree_taxons`.`parent_id` = 6818
```

I can't tell where this ouput could come from. Maybe something in Rails is logging to `stderr` or `stdout`, but a `DEBUG` shouldn't be in production. Any ideas where to start searching for this stuff? When I start the app in production on my local machine, I don't get this errors in the log files.

thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spawner is the subsystem in Passenger that spawns application processes. The Preloader is an auxiliary application process used for reducing the time needed to spawn multiple processes and for greater memory efficiency through the use of copy-on-write virtual memory. More information here:

- http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#spawning_methods_explained
- http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Architectural%20overview.html

Whether a preloader process is used is determined by the PassengerSpawnMethod directive.

The Preloader is shut down after an inactivity timeout, just like normal application processes, in order to conserve resources. If Passenger keeps telling you that the Preloader keeps being started then that means the Preloader becomes inactive, and becomes active again, and at that moment is started again. This is harmless but if you prefer it not doing that then you should tweak [PassengerMaxPreloaderIdleTime](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerMaxPreloaderIdleTime). You might always want to tweak PassengerMinInstances to make your application process pool static instead of dynamic.